# Why in logistic regression for every threshold the decision boundary is a hyperplane?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

I'm a beginner in machine learning study and I can't figure it out an exercise:

The function `h(x) = θ(w  ̃x)` is used to approximate `P(y = +1 | x)`. So x = +1 if `h(x) > T` and -1 if `h(x) < T` for a certain threshold `T ∈ [0, 1]` . If `h(x) = T` then x is in the decision boundary. The question is: how can I matematically prove that for any threshold T the decision boundary is an hyperplane?

Comment: If $\theta:\mathbb R\to ]0,1[$ denotes the usual sigmoid function $\theta(y)=\frac1{1+e^{-y}}$, then $\theta$ is bijective, so for $T\in ]0,1[$ fixed, we have $h(x)=T$ iff $\langle w, x\rangle=\theta^{-1}(T)$. But this is exactly the equation defining a hyperplane. If $T=1$ or $T=0$, we obtain the empty set instead of a hyperplane.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @William, the problem I saw declares that for any value of T, the decision boundary is a hyperplane. So, θ(w  ̃x) > T is a hyperplane, θ(w  ̃x) < T is a hyperplane and θ(w  ̃x) = T is a hyperplane. What I want is to mathematically demonstrate that this is true.